# Workaround for temporary files in Google App Engine [Java]

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm writing a web app with App Engine in Java. I need to add a QR Code in a PDF and allow users to download the generated PDF. I could make it work locally but I have some troubles when I upload it to App Engine.

I'm using [QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen) which allow me to generate a `File` with the QR code from text. The problem is because QRGen uses File.createTempFile([Line 90](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen/blob/master/core/src/main/java/net/glxn/qrgen/core/AbstractQRCode.java)) in order to create the temporary file and App Engine don't allow developers to create temporary file. When I upload it to App Engine I receive a `net.glxn.qrgen.core.exception.QRGenerationException` in [Line 129](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen/blob/master/javase/src/main/java/net/glxn/qrgen/javase/QRCode.java).

I'd like to receive suggestions about how can I handle this issue:

1. Should I modify QRGen in order to not use temporary files? Which method/function could I use to replace File.createTempFile and not have problems with App Engine
2. Is there any workaround in App Engine to handle with temporary images?

Comment: App Engine Flexible Environment should allow you to write to the filesystem. Just note the temp file will only be available on the instance you created it.

Comment: Why don't u use the writeToStream() method instead of the file-generating method?